# In R merge checks

Tags: r, merge

For simple 1:1 merge for example:

```
    data_merge <- (dataset1, dataset2, by.x = "name", by.y = "name")
```

Is there a way to run a check of the values successfully merged, i.e., a count or flag of those only in merged into the data set from the dataset1, and those only merged in from dataset2, and those successfully matched from both?

Comment: You should post code (which that is clearly not)  used and a dataset to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The `tidylog` package provides that for dplyr/tidyr operations. For instance,

```
library(dplyr); library(tidylog)
left_join(band_members, band_instruments)
```

Result

```
Joining, by = "name"
left_join: added one column (plays)
           > rows only in x   1
           > rows only in y  (1)
           > matched rows     2
           >                 ===
           > rows total       3
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  name  band    plays 
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> 
1 Mick  Stones  NA    
2 John  Beatles guitar
3 Paul  Beatles bass
```